# Pull records from one table where 1 variable exists in a second table? Very large tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sas

I am completely new to database coding, and I've tried Googling but cannot seem to figure this out. I imagine there's a simple solution. I have a very large table with MemberIDs and a few other relevant variables that I want to pull records from (table1). I also have a second large table of distinct MemberIDs (table2). I want to pull rows from table 1 where the MemberID exists in table2.

Here’s how I tried to do it, and for some reason I suspect this isn’t working correctly, or there may be a much better way to do this.

```
proc sql; 
create table tablewant as select
MemberID, var1, var2, var3
from table1
where exists (select MemberID from table2)
;
quit;
```

Is there anything wrong with the way I’m doing this? What's the best way to solve this when working with extremely large tables (over 100 million records)? Would doing some sort of join be better? Also, do I need to change

```
where exists (select MemberID from table2)
```

to

```
where exists (select MemberID from table2 where table1.MemberID = table2.MemberID)
```

?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. You say: "I want to pull rows from table 1 where the MemberID exists in table2", but you also say that all the rows adhere to this rule... so essentially you want **all the rows**. Retrieving 100 million rows will take some time.

Comment: @TheImpaler Apologies for that, that line "There are no MemberIDs in table 1 that do not exist in table2." was incorrect and I removed it from my post. There are indeed some MemberIDs in table1 that do not exist in table2. Sorry again, it's been a long day.

Comment: Did not try `where MemberID in (select distinct MemberID from BIG)`, in other words what made you focus on existential query ?  Are you seeing log messages with ERRORs or running out of resources ?  Also, a hash based lookup for membership is also very fast.  A scan of a 100M records from a SAS data set, with attendant lookup is not particularly horrific.  Is your query being performed in a remote data base ?

Answer (score 1):

You want to implement a "semi-join". You second solution is correct:

```
select MemberID, var1, var2, var3
from table1
where exists (
  select 1 from table2 where table1.MemberID = table2.MemberID
)
```

Notes:

- There's no need to select anything special in the subquery since it's not checking for values, but for *row existence* instead. For example, `1` will do, as well as `*`, or even `null`. I tend to use `1` for clarity.
- The query needs to access `table2` and this should be optimized specially for such large tables. You should consider adding the index below, if you haven't created it already:

  ```
    create index ix1 on table2 (MemberID);
  ```
- The query does not have a filtering criteria. That means that the engine will read 100 million rows and will check each one of them for the matching rows in the secondary table. This will unavoidably take a long time. Are you sure you want to read them all? Maybe you need to add a filtering condition, but I don't know your requirements in this respect.

Comment: This is incredibly helpful, thank you! I do want to read all the rows from table2 and thus won't be able to use a filtering criteria, but I appreciate the suggestion. One follow up question: I haven't heard of indexes before, but I think I'll add that line to my code. A Google search says "Indexes are used to retrieve data from the database more quickly than otherwise. The users cannot see the indexes, they are just used to speed up searches/queries.", is this all I need to know about indexes?

Comment: Also, do I need to create the index within the subquery? Or where would you place that line within the code?

Comment: @haveylife The index is created beforehand, and only once.